# Ansible - replace particular string in multiple files if file exists

Tags: ansible

I can replace a string in the file if the file exists in a directory.

Similarly, I want to replace the string in another 25 files (`test2.conf` .. `test25.conf`) if the files exist in the same directory. Using with_items I can able to replace a string in all files but unable to use the register to check the file exists in the loop.

Below playbook is a success for one file, how can I achieve the same for 25 files?

```
     - hosts: webserver  

       vars:
    strings:
       - user1
       - user2

  tasks:  
     - name: Check /home/user/test1.conf exists
       stat:  
          path: /home/user/test1.conf  
       register: stat_result


 - name:  Replace string in test1.conf
   replace:
     dest: /home/user/test1.conf
     backup: yes
     regexp: '^Hello'
     replace: "Hello {{ strings | join(' ')}}"
   when: stat_result.stat.exists == True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` module instead of `stat` and iterate over the results:

```
- hosts: webserver  

  vars:
    strings:
      - user1
      - user2

  tasks:  
    - name: Get a list of test*.conf in /home/user
      find:  
        paths: /home/user
        patterns: test*.conf
       register: my_find

    - name: Replace strings in files found
      replace:
        dest: "{{ item.path }}"
        backup: yes
        regexp: '^Hello'
        replace: "Hello {{ strings | join(' ')}}"
      with_items: "{{ my_find.files }}"
```

---

<sup>Your `replace` task is not idempotent, it will add `strings` infinitely on subsequent runs.</sup>

Comment: it worked. Thanks a lot and just want to know how can we can check the files and replace string in `/home/user1` if all files don't exist in `/home/user`  @techraf